# Lanzar una excepcion sin recogerla en la funcion

Tags: java, excepciones

Me gustaria saber porque el primer codigo funciona y el segundo me obliga a añadir el throw en el metodo y como corregirlo para que no sea necesario.

Ejemplo 1 funcional:

```
public void run(){ 
 try{ 
  doSomethingThatLaunchAException();
 }catch(IOException e){
  logger.error("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    throw new RuntimeException();
 }
}
```

Ejemplo 2 con mi propia interfaz.

```
public void run() throw MiPropiaExcepcion{ 
 try{ 
  doSomethingThatLaunchAException();
 }catch(IOException e){
  logger.error("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    throw new MiPropiaExcepcion();
 }
}
```

Comment: Que tiene mi MiPropiaExcepcion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

con respecto a tu pregunta todo depende de cual Excepción extiende tu clase MiPropiaExcepcion, si extiende 'Exception' será obligatorio especificar en el 'throw' el manejo de la excepción, pero si tu clase extiende de 'RuntimeException' entonce no sera obligatorio el retornar el error en la firma del método, tu clase quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
public class MiPropiaExcepcion extends RuntimeException
```